# Is it a standards breach to have unescaped href URIs in <a> links?

Tags: html

In a HTML 4.01 Transitional document, is it a breach of the standard to specify a link href without escaping space characters?

For instance this link

```
<a href="http://example.com/some page.html">Some page</a>
```

as opposed to

```
<a href="http://example.com/some%20page.html">Some page</a>
```

I can't easily work it out from http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/links.html#h-12.1.3 , maybe one of you folks can enlighten?

Comment: +1 Had someone asked me to guess before seeing the answers to this question, I would have guessed incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In a HTML 4.01 Transitional document, is it a breach of the standard to specify a link href without escaping space characters?

Yes. The [href attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-href), [takes a URI](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-uri) as defined in RFC1630, RFC1738 and RFC1808.

RFC1738 says:

> The space
>   character is unsafe because significant spaces may disappear and
>   insignificant spaces may be introduced when URLs are transcribed or
>   typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-processing programs.

and

> All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL.

Answer (score 2):

The `href` attribute value [is a URI](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/links.html#adef-href), as specified in [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

Which says (section 2.4.3. Excluded US-ASCII Characters):

> The space character is excluded because significant spaces may
>      disappear and insignificant spaces may be introduced when URI are
>      transcribed or typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-
>      processing programs.

So, you **must** encode spaces.